# Threadsafe/non-clobbering foreach file container for SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio

I'm attempting to modify a SSIS package in Visual Studio's "File Reader Integration Services" to process multiple `ForEach File Enumerator`s at the same time (each for different file sub-types), but it seems that setting e.g. @User::ProcessFile in one sets it so that in the "global" (package-wide) scope, it clobbers the value previously set in another simultaneously executing `ForEach File Enumerator`. The result of this is that my `Connection Manager` within the enumerator attempts to process a type of file that's inappropriate given that enumerator.

I see that there's a way to set the variable scope, but it doesn't work as desired. Plus it's a PITA.

1. Open the `Variables` tab
2. Click on the "Grid Options" icon (far right)
3. In the Filter section click "Show variables of all scopes"
4. Make sure "Scope", "Data type" and "Namespace" (at the very least) are clicked in the Columns section.
5. Click "OK"
6. Repeat the following for each ForEach File Enumerator (we'll call each "*ffe*" when it's the one selected)

   1. "Add Variable"(upper-left icon) and name to "ProcessFile"
   2. Select the "Data Type" dropdown and select "String"
   3. Set the "Namespace" column to "lcl"
   4. "Move Variable" (second-from-left icon)
   5. Expand "Executables"
   6. Select "*ffe*" from the list
   7. Click "OK"
7. Now for each *ffe* container

   1. Open the Foreach Loop Editor
   2. Click on "Variable Mappings"
   3. Set the value of Index 0 to "lcl::ProcessFile"
   4. Click "OK"

There doesn't appear to be a Copy Variable option (either via icon, mouse/context menu or keyboard shortcut), so there doesn't seem to be an easy way to have the variable represented in the global space as well as in each sub-container scoped to only itself.

However, as the "Package Explorer tab shows "Connection Managers" as a separate group from the "Executables", variables made local to the scope of the Foreach File Enumerator executable aren't visible to any of the Connection Manager entries.  The error given is `The variable "lcl::ProcessFile" was not found in the Variables collection. The variable might not exist in the correct scope`, as it's not a GLOBAL variable.

Is there a way to move the connection managers to be children of the executables, or a way of specifying the parent scope for each Connection Manager?

Is there a way to set a variable value for a connection manager without depending on either a constant value or a reference to the global variable space? Can "variable variables" be made to e.g. use a different prefix for each subcontainer?

Comment: It seems I can get it to work by using a different namespace (or variable name) for each container in the global variable space, but this still requires most of the manual muckery of steps 6&7 above. There's got to be a simpler way!